# How to add menu tab with dropdown list to woocommerce my account page

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to add a dropdown list item to woo commerce myaccount page. 
Here is my code

```
add_action( 'init', 'loyalty_points_my_account_new_endpoints' );    

function loyalty_points_my_account_new_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'loyalty_points', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}   

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'loyalty_points_my_account_menu_items', 10, 1 );
function loyalty_points_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {    
    $items['loyalty_points'] = __( 'Loyalty Rewards', 'my account' );    
    return $items;    
}    

/**
* Get new endpoint content
*/    
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_loyalty_points_endpoint', 'loyalty_points_endpoint_content' );
function loyalty_points_endpoint_content() { 
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'frontend/loyalty-reward-points.php');
}
```

Now I am getting Loyalty Rewards tab in myaccount page, but I want Loyalty Rewards tab with dropdown list items and every list item get different page template when select those links .

[image: Screenshot]

Please check above picture.I want like this and each list item with separate template calling

Comment: Hey, did you ever get that solved?

Comment: No it is not solved i did not get any solution for this